# Azure Databricks move Log Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, azure-log-analytics

Databricks VMs are pointing to Default Log Analytics but I want to point them to another one

If I try to move VMs to antoher workpacks it tells me that its locked

Error: cannot perform delete operation because following scope(s) are locked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you are not allowed to move Log Analytics for the Managed Resource Group created in Azure Databricks using Azure portal.

**Reason:** By default, you cannot perform any write operation on the managed resource group which created by Azure Databricks.

If you try to modify anything in the managed resource group, you will see this error message:

```
{"details":[{"code":"ScopeLocked","message":"The scope '/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/databricks-rg-chepra-d7ensl75cgiki' cannot perform write operation because following scope(s) are locked: '/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/databricks-rg-chepra-d7ensl75cgiki'. Please remove the lock and try again."}]}
Possible way: You can specify tags as key-value pairs when while creating/modifying clusters, and Azure Databricks will apply these tags to cloud resources.
```

**Possible way:** Configure your Azure Databricks cluster to use the monitoring library.

This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/databricks-monitoring/application-logs) shows how to send application logs and metrics from Azure Databricks to a Log Analytics workspace. It uses the Azure Databricks Monitoring Library.

Hope this helps.